# Crack the code using the clues

Tags: puzzle

Can anyone Crack this code  by elaborating the clues 
[image]

Ans;042

Comment: It's straightforward if you just go through each clue. You do have to assume, however, that each clue will identify every correct number in the clue, and that it won't address one correct number, but not another. Most people will assume it anyway, but this fact is necessary. What's really interesting to note is that you can take out at least one of the clues, and still find the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From (1) and (2) we can find 6 is not number. So from (1) either 8 is correct or 2. Then from (4) we can see 8 is not correct. So we left with 2. Fill it on 3rd place.

From (3) two numbers are correct. As 6 cannot be the number we left with 0, 2. And 2 is already in 3rd place. And 0 on second place is wrong. So we have 0 on first place.

From (2) we know 6 can't be the number. We left with 1 and 4. We can't place 1 on first or third place. So it is not the number. We left with 4 and second position.

So answer is 042.

Answer (score 2):

From $4th$ we know that $7,3,8$ are not part of the answer.

In $5th$ we discover $0$ as solution and cannot be in $3rd$ position.

Comparing $1$ and $2$ we know that $6$ cannot be part of the answer as a contradiction, $8$ isn't part of solution as well. Therefore we discover digit $2$ in third position.

Note that on $3rd$, $6$ as solution was discarded so $0,2$ is solution but in wrong position since $0$ cannot be $3rd$ nor $2nd$ it must be $1st$. Now we have $0x2$.

Now checking $2nd$ we notice that for getting $x$ we need middle value, since $6$ isn't a solution we select $4$ since placing it in middle will make a well placed. Then $042$.